# How to link custom tables to a module and get those data from HELPER class. Mage::getHelper('mymodule/table1')->getCollection()?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to link custom tables to a module and get those data from HELPER class.

Mage::getHelper('mymodule/table1')->getCollection()

Please send example.

Answer (score 0):

Your module naming convention is quite confusing - you're calling the module itself helper? For the purpose of explaining, I'm choosing to call your module `myname_mymodule`

In your module `./app/code/community/MyName/MyModule/etc/config.xml`, within the `<global>` tags

```
<helpers>
      <mymodule>
          <class>MyName_MyModule_Helper</class>
      </mymodule>
    </helpers>
```

Then create the file `./app/code/community/MyName/MyModule/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class MyName_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

Then to call that module, you would use

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mymodule');
```

Comment: Can I use link custom table with module using helper class ?? Using Model I got it and set/get data easily but in case of Helper or other class except Model class I confused.

Comment: Please explain with examples. Above you telling about how to use Helper class but how configure table with Helper class so that I can set or get data using this Helper class.Thanks